# Creating a new webproject with MonoDevelop 2.1 under Mac OS X => exception

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I have a fresh install of MonoDevelop 2.1 and Mono-Framework 2.7. When I try to create a new project, the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of   an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Add-in    
'MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser,2.1.0' could not be loaded. 
at Mono.Addins.ExtensionNode.get_Addin () [0x00081] in /tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-addins-0.4/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionNode.cs:102 
at Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode.get_Type () [0x00026] in /tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-addins-0.4/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/TypeExtensionNode.cs:62
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage both of those packages are probably "young" enough to be well understood by creator only, who may not be monitoring StackOverflow as carefully as their project's mailing lists. So I think it would be better to ask that question in [MonoDevelop](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list) or [Mono](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-devel-list) mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

I second what Piotr said -- I'm an MD developer, and I check Stack Overflow pretty infrequently. The best thing would be to [report the bug](http://monodevelop.com/Developers#Reporting_Bugs) to make sure it's tracked so it can be fixed in future releases.

Also, try "`rm -r ~/.config/MonoDevelop/addin*`" in a terminal, to force rebuilding the addin registry.

(BTW, I assume you mean Mono 2.4_7, not 2.7)